# get ruby hash key value using Erubis

Tags: ruby, erubis

I have a hash:

```
hash = "email_address"=>"test@example.com"
```

I would like to get the value from this hash which is "test@example.com" using erubis.  This doesn't work:

```
<% 
pp hash.[email_address]
%>
```

Comment: provide the `params` value for more help

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
<%= pp hash["email_address"] %>
```

or

```
<%= pp hash[:email_address] %>
```

Comment: also i tried the second one and this what i got: can't convert Symbol into Integer

Comment: The `hash` variable you have, is it an Array or Hash?

Comment: if I am not mistaken it is hash..... Other than email_address I am getting other hashes as well..
"email_address"=>"test@example.com", "phone_number"=>"434344", "mobile_number"=>"56546565",

Comment: Not necessary. It can be an array of hashes. Try to print `hash.class`.

Comment: OMG. I am sorry but I guess I can't help here.